# Magento2 : Getting error in console customer-data.js:86

Tags: magento2, error, frontend-error, console, customer-data

I am using Magento2.1.9 getting this `error` in our `console` i am trying to different solutions but not fix it.please if any one know reply me

[image]

Comment: I ain't sure but I think its due to local storage, You can give a try to clear local storage data and clear cookie. It should work.

Comment: yes but i m not clear every time in console any solution for other way

Comment: After clearing local storage does error disappear ?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that customer-data.js uses the localStorage to store a variety of stuff (probably for caching purposes). This means that when a module (or Magento) updates, you'd better make sure to flush your local storage as well.

**Reference - You can find some more solution here :**

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6410

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/9db4501d29028ba9ac552f14d80b42bc923847f4/app/code/Magento/Review/etc/frontend/di.xml#L32